# Removing numbering gaps inside sorted SQLite column

Tags: sqlite, parallel.foreach

inside a SQLite-DB is a table which has two rows (ID, Start). When the table is sorted by Start-column, the ID must have a continous numbering.

**Example for current contents:**

ID {0, 44, 88, 132...} Start {0, 44, 88, 132...}

**Result which I need:**

ID {1, 2, 3, 4...} and Start {0, 44, 88, 132...}

This code for correcting the ID-column works, but for larger tables it needs to much time:

```
        using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (var cmdRows = new SQLiteCommand(
                "SELECT Start FROM Tokens ORDER BY Start ASC;", conn))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = cmdRows.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int id = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        id += 1;
                        var cmdID = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
                        cmdID.CommandText =
                            "UPDATE Tokens SET ID=" + id.ToString() +
                            " WHERE Start=" + reader["Start"].ToString();
                        cmdID.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

The code which generates 3 tables and executed directly before, contents 3 loops (1 nested and a further one nested in the nested). The outer loop is made as Parallel.ForEach, which increases the speed 2x. But in addition with the above code it runs in the speed problem for large tables. With the Parallel.ForEach I'm not able to get the ID-column chronological in continous numbering. With serial loops I don't need the above code, the result is fine but slower for large tables.

At the moment my only acceptable solution is giving up the Parallel.ForEach and go back to the normal ForEach.

An overview of what is trying to be solved is :-

The ID is not the rowid.

I have a tokenizer which analysis text and I need a variable which idendifies each token/word in the text with its order number.

This enables finding a text structure such as ***Show all text part where an auxillary verb is followed by the continous form of a verb:*** e,g :-

In ***We are swimming now*** (find "are swimming") which would be `SELECT .... WHERE t1.Attr='aux' and t2.Attr='converb' and t1.id=t2.id-1`

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a tokenizer which analysis text and I need a variable which idendifies each token/word in the text with its order number. 

This enables finding a text structure such as ***Show all text parts where an auxillary verb is followed by the continous form of a verb:*** e,g :-

In ***We are swimming now*** (find "are swimming") which would be `SELECT .... WHERE t1.Attr='aux' and t2.Attr='converb' and t1.id=t2.id-1`

Answer (score 0):

Assigning consecutive IDs can be done with a single SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Tokens
SET ID = (SELECT count(*)
          FROM Tokens AS T2
          WHERE T2.Start <= Tokens.Start);
```

However, doing a single UPDATE for each entry is likely to be faster because the database does not have to do the counting for each row.

In any case, both algorithms need an index on the `Start` column to be efficient.

Comment: This SQL works and is perfect for small tables. But for larger tables (>100k rows) it takes a couple of minutes even the columns are indexed.

Comment: It rewrites every row of the table, i.e., the entire table.